# DynamoDB-Java write if exists update if not

Tags: java, database, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB and would like to try to update some entries and insert ones that do not exist. My current code look like this:

```
updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                .withPrimaryKey(ITable.ID,
                 request.getID().getValue())
                .withUpdateExpression(updatedExpressionSetString)
                .withNameMap(nameMap)
                .withValueMap(valueMap)
try {
        table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
}
```

Where the updateExpression is:

```
SET supply.#var0 = 
if_not_exists(supply.#var0,:default) + :val0,
date = :dateVal
```

This all works great until a reach a entry where the primary key does not already exist. When this happens this code throws the exception:

The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;)

My question is: How do I correct this code so that it will insert when it reaches a primary key, update when it reaches a primary key that already exists without requiring a additional read to check if it exists beforehand?

Comment: have you tried to run this with a table that has no primary key?

Comment: Well the table is empty be default but I still need to keep the primary key or else I get a _cannot have null key for GetItem, DeleteItem, or UpdateItem error_

Comment: I mean try isolate the problem. Try a simple update if it works then you know the problem is the if exists. I don't have access to my java environment now

Comment: If I try to do an update to the table without anything in it. (No primary key) It w fails with a "The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update" the same happens if I first insert a different primary key then the one in the updateItemSpec. From my isolation I think that the failure occurs because  table.updateItem cannot find a entry with that primary key to update. Is there anyway to cause it to a Upsert using only 1 write?

Comment: More time later

Comment: Added answer because post b became too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not recall if the PK was mandatory. It is. From the java docs:

> if_not_exists (path, operand) - if the item does not contain an
>   attribute at the specified path, then if_not_exists evaluates to
>   operand; otherwise, it evaluates to path. You can use this function to
>   avoid overwriting an attribute that may already be present in the
>   item.

But this

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.UpdateData.html

states it is possible.

The value does not seem to be the PK. Does the upsert work on the table without an expression?